# Catching exceptions in a list comprehension

Tags: python, exception, list-comprehension

I did a list comprehension with

```
result =[df_dict[letter] for letter in user_input]
```

this works aslong the letter is a key in df_dict. Now i tried to catch exceptions, but i cant figure out how i pass the latter if a Key Error occurs if I wanna use a list comprehension.

This is the solution i found so far.

```
result =[]
for letter in user_input:
    try:
        result.append(df_dict[letter])
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Comment: If `user_input` is a string then you could also do `[df_dict[c] for c in df_dict.keys() & user_input]`

Answer (score 0):

You can not catch exception in comprehension, but for dictionary, you can use `.get` method passing the key, which won't raise any error if key doesn't exist.

```py
>>> result =[df_dict.get(letter) for letter in user_input]
```

But above solution will create a list with `None` values if key doesn't exist in the dictionary so you'll have to first check if the key is in the dictionary or not:

```py
>>> [df_dict[letter] for letter in user_input and letter in df_dict]
```

But if you are using Python 3.9+, you can also use [named expression using `:=`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#syntax-and-semantics), here is an example

```py
>>> d={'a':5}
>>> [v for k in "abc" if k in 'abcd' and (v:=d.get(k)) is not None]
[5]
```

Comment: I guess this will work also :
result =[df_dict[letter] for letter in user_input if letter in df_dict]